# $\sup_{(a,b)\in B_2(0,1)}\left\{\max(|a+2b|,|b+2a|)\right\}=2\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Let
$$B_2(0,1):=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{C}^2;\;|a|^2+|b|^2<1\}.$$

> I want to calculate
>   $$N:=\sup_{(a,b)\in B_2(0,1)}\left\{\max(|a+2b|,|b+2a|)\right\}.$$

**My attempt:** Since for all $(a,b)\in B_2(0,1)$ we have
$$\max\{|a+2b|,|b+2a|\}\leq 2(|a|+|b|)\leq 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{|a|^2+|b|^2}<2\sqrt{2},$$
it follows that  $N\leq 2\sqrt{2}$.

> It is possible to show that $N=2\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: If your claim is true, then we should have attain the maximum since the set $B_{2}(0, 1)$ is compact. However, there's no $(a, b)\in B_{2}(0, 1)$ s.t. all the equalities holds in your inequalities. So $N<2\sqrt{2}$, I think.

Comment: $B_2(0,1)$ is the open unit ball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that by [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality):
$$|a+2b|\leq \sqrt{|a|^2+|b|^2} \cdot \sqrt{1^2+2^2}.$$
Moreover consider for $n\geq 1$, the sequence $(a_n,b_n)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5+\frac{1}{n}}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{5+\frac{1}{n}}}\right)\in B_2(0,1).$

Comment: The link doens't work.

Comment: @Schüler Try now.

Comment: @Schüler "Do you think that $N=\sqrt 5$?" Yes. What did you try to show this?

Comment: @Schüler Yes. Try to prove it.

Comment: Thnak you for your help. I will try to prove it.

Comment: By the inequality $N\leq \sqrt{5}$. Did you prove that $N=\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: @RobertZ Yes thanks a lot for your help.